# Routes with syncHistoryWithStore doesn't work and doesn't show errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm creating routes and I'm stuck on `syncHistoryWithStore`, it doesn't work. There are no errors on the console or anything, it just doesn't load components.

However if I simply use `createBrowserHistory` without the sync it works, clicking links do change the components

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));

// Doesn't work: Doesn't load components, page doesn't change (without a full reload)
// No errors on the console
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store);

// Works
// const history = createBrowserHistory();

render(
  <Provider store={ store } key="provider">
    <Router history={ history }>
    ...
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } />
            <Route path="/about" component={ About } />
            <Route path="*" component={ NoMatch }/>
          </Switch>
```

package.json

```
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2",
"react-redux": "^5.0.3",
"react-router": "^4.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
```

Is there anything specific that I have to do for this to work? Is there perhaps an example somewhere with the latest version of things?

Or should I just use `createBrowserHistory` without the sync?

Comment: Any luck? I am having exactly the same issue with you.